# Azure database asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-storage, azure-sql-database

There is my situation:
I have created an azure SQL database and an MVC solution witch is connected to the database. I created models for my application and used scaffolding to create controllers and views automatically. It worked and I can use everything fine with those views!

But now I wish to use my database in different way!

Let's say I have a table Client with 3 columns Id, name, nbPeople. Because I used the scaffolding, in my view controller, under index method, I got this function return View (db.Client.ToList()); that list every things in my Client table.

It's great but now, my question finally, how can I do, for example, to just list the name?

I hope someone have a solution and will give it to me! ;)

Comment: Use Select on DbSet: `db.Client.Select(c => c.name).ToList()`

Comment: I think this is the way I want to do it but when I try this I got this error : The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List 1[System.Int32]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1 , because the view of index is using a @model IEnumerable how can I fix this ?

Comment: As error points You need to adjust view as well. Set '@model IList<int>' in view if 'name' property is 'int'.

Comment: Ok I got it  ! I will have lot of fun with all these days ! Thank you ! Just one more question : the select is only usable on one column or more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GO to html view generated by scaffolding (e.g. Index.cshtml) in Views folder. You can see html tags where Id and People fields are used to display. Remove those html tags. So your view will display only Name. Hope this is what you want, just to display list of names.

Comment: I already tried this way but is it a really a good practice? Shouldn't I pass what I want to show in the View method instead of "hiding" informations ?

Comment: Ideally model object you use for displaying data on view should be different from database entity. And you should fetch data from database and map it to your model.

Comment: Ok thank you I see it more clearly !